# How to connect from one EC2 instance to another EC2 (Redis) instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I have 2 EC2 instances - on one is installed a Rails app (and connected to RDS MySQL database). This works well.
Then I created another EC2 instance where is installed Redis. I have defined here a user, port, password and namespace.

However, I am having issues to successfully connect there.

Here are 2 places in my Rails app where I am trying to connect to this Redis instance:

`deploy/production.rb`:

```
  config.cache_store = :redis_store, { host:      "deployer_redis:IP",
                                       port:      6379,
                                       db:        env_num,
                                       password:  "...my password...",
                                       namespace: "cache" }
```

and
`config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`:

```
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url:       "redis://deployer_redis:password_here@IP:6379/#{env_num}", 
                     namespace: "sidekiq_shiptis_com_#{Rails.env}" }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url:       "redis://deployer_redis:password_here@IP:6379/#{env_num}", 
                     namespace: "sidekiq_shiptis_com_#{Rails.env}" }
  end
```

But when I try to deploy the code, capistrano fails because the app cannot connect to the remote Redis host.

When I looked on the security group of this Redis EC2 instance (t2.micro), it's name is **launch-wizard-5** and there are these inbound rules:

```
SSH                TCP      22    0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule    TCP    6379    0.0.0.0/0
```

What piece of config am I missing?
How to make the EC2 Rails instance communicate with EC2 Redis instance?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your `redis` server listening on 127.0.0.1:6379 or 0.0.0.0:6379 (Check netstat output)

Comment: Hey @helloV, when I log in to the redis instance, `netstat -nlp` doesn't show redis in the output. When I run redis (`redis-server`), I see `17:36:04.274 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379`.

Comment: What is the output of: `sudo netstat -plan | grep -i redis`

Comment: This is the output:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1237/redis-server *
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      1237/redis-server *`

Comment: It is listening for all connections which is correct. Is there a firewall rule? If you could post the error message, we may get a clue.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that the Redis instance was terminated. So I started it, which automatically change the IP of the server. So I update this IP address in the Rails app and then when I loaded the app, I got a different error: `ActionView::Template::Error (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):` - on the rows in the views where is used caching. Tried to restart the server (unicorn), but it didn't help.

Comment: Also, I tried to log in to the EC2 Redis instance and run `redis-server`, but the same result/error.

Comment: As-of-now solution: in `config/environments/production.rb`, I changed `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` to `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false` and now it seems to be working.